# Verb followed by 3 prepositions: ".......looking out across through their eyes ...... | Is this a slip of tongue or something else?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, colloquial-language, connected-speech

*Most people, when they think about themselves, have this experience or this very powerful phenomena that they exist inside their heads, sort of looking **out across through** their eyes, controlling their hands and their limbs like a puppet master.* [BBC - Exploring the essence of human experience](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oBE2Wr7kpk) (see: 6:33-6:48)

The expression **".....looking out across through their eyes..."** caught my attention as the word **"look"** is followed by 3 prepositions simultaneously.

I looked up all 3 of them, and all of them have their own meaning. But when they are used together with "eyes", only the last one sounds right.

**- to look out their eyes,** (wrong)

**- to look across their eyes,** (wrong)

**- to look through their eyes.** (right)

So, is it simply a slip of tongue to use all 3 prepositions (which don't make sense)? although it is the last one that he means to say?

Comment: You can look out across an expanse. Presumably the "powerful phenomena [sic]" is "looking out across [some expanse] through their eyes"

Comment: Not a slip of tongue, but speaking extemporaneously and considering three synonymous prepositions: "... out/across/through their eyes." I wouldn't put any weight in it.

Comment: The subtitles are incorrect. He says "phenomenon".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's just unscripted *speech* where the speaker is obviously struggling to express complex yet nebulous concepts. The fact that he inappropriately follows halting ***sort of*** by a verb with ***three*** prepositions isn't worth spending time on.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, do you mean those prepositions are just synonymous, but the speaker uses them all together because he can't decide which one to use?

Comment: "to look through their eyes" would not be wrong, but obviously metaphorical. Likewise "to look out OF their eyes" would be ok, and metaphorical again.

Comment: @timchessish, sorry, I mistyped it. Edited now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yes, people speak and decide how they want to say *what* they want to say in the process. @FumbleFingers explains more fully.

Comment: @yunus: As a general principle, if an Anglophone speaker you're listening to uses "filler" terms (um, hmm, well, ah, sort of, kinda,...) you shouldn't spend too much time analyzing the exact syntax of what he says. Unscripted speech (especially, *in front of a camera*) will often contain "errors" that you really don't want to learn or copy yourself!

Comment: looking out across [the world] through their [own] eyes **Connected speech** has a lot of truncations, omissions and repetitions.

Comment: @Lambie, Thanks, that was what I have been looking for. Breaking down the prepositions along with the words in parantheses helped me understand the reason why they all came together.

Comment: It always amazes me how people become moralistic about these issues of speech, before analyzing the situation. I am sure everyone here knows this but they are not necessarily trained as "listeners" as we interpreters are. Cheers and Happy New Year. I think the question should remain open for this exact reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks. Yes, the exact syntax might not be nice in unscripted language. But, definitely he means to say something. And when it comes to translating his speech fully, it must include everyting - even his hesitations and struggle with choice of words-, and you must create the same effect in the target language. You can't simply skip it and write on the screen that "these parts are not not worth spending time on". Nor can you leave that part without translation at all, because then people would be curious what he was saying in those moments. This is why I wanted every bit of it.

Comment: @yunus: I don't think that's a realistic position for a *learner* to take. Learners aren't the people who should be entrusted with creating "accurate" translations of foreign text *inclusive of the subtle implications of a speaker struggling to find the right words*. If you need to ask here what the words "mean", you really should take the advice "Ignore them".